# Find and Replace, with Conditional Delete

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to

- search for a specific term within a Word document and then delete the line that this term shows up on.
- check if the previous paragraph has ended with a period or quotation mark, and if so, press the delete key twice (to join the previous paragraph to the one that comes after).

I get 500+ page Word documents that have been converted from PDF. The headers are never removed from these docs before conversion, and so I have to remove them. Sometimes they fall after a paragraph, and sometimes they fall mid-paragraph and break that paragraph in two.

Through trial, error, and googling I managed to write some VBA to search for these headers and delete them, but I then have to manually check if the a paragraph has been interrupted and fix it. The specifics of conditional VBA and checking for missing periods from my cursor position is beyond me.

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Selection
    .Find.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Text = "thing"
    .Find.Execute
    .MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    .TypeBackspace
    End With
End Sub
```

The code works for checking for any instances of the header — assuming the header began with "thing" in this case — and deleting that line.

How do I check the previous paragraph for missing periods or quotation marks and execute a couple of backspaces?

Comment: I've posted an Answer based on what I *understand* the question to be. It's uncertain, however, exactly how these documents are constructed. For something like this it would help to include screen shots of 1) before "find" and 2) after you've *manually* made the correction. Also, the display of non-printing characters (paragraph marks, spaces) should be on so that we can see the structures. If I did not correctly understand, please use the [edit] link below the question to add these.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the code in the question to the description I'm assuming that "deleting that line" means that the "headers" that need to be removed are in their own ***paragraph***, not just in "a line". This is an important distinction in Word, as lines break automatically when the content is too long; a paragraph is where ENTER is pressed and is a separate "entity".

I've started with the code in the question and built on it. Notice, first, the test for whether something was actually found: `bFound = .Find.Execute`. `Execute` returns True or False. The value of `bFound` is tested and only if True, does the code continue.

If true, a `Range` object is set to the *entire paragraph* that contains the found item. (Think of `Range` objects like invisible selections. If you know how, these are easier to work with and, more importantly, you can work with as many as you need. There's always only *one* `Selection`.)

This paragraph is then deleted, which if I'm following the problem description correctly, leaves you with two paragraphs adjacent (no empty ones). The question now being, does the paragraph *before* end with a `?` or a `.`.

So the starting point is moved backwards (think of it like holding Shift while pressing Left-Arrow) until a `.` or a `?` is located; a negative number is returned. If the number of characters moved is minus three or greater, everything is OK. (Three or greater: the paragraph mark is one character; there could, conceivably, be a space following the punctuation; the punctuation, itself.)

If the move was more characters (a negative number) then the paragraph was broken up. In this case, the `Range` is collapsed to where it was before checking for punctuation (which should be the beginning of the paragraph following what was found), the starting point moved back again, but by only one character (should be the paragraph mark), then deleted. The result: the paragraph before and following the found term are combined.

```
Sub FindCheckDocStructure()
    Dim rngFound As Word.Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim countMoved As Long

    With Selection
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        .Find.Text = "thing"
        bFound = .Find.Execute
        If bFound Then
            Set rngFound = .Paragraphs(1).Range
            rngFound.Delete
            countMoved = rngFound.MoveStartUntil(".?", wdBackward)
            If countMoved >= -3 Then
                'OK, do nothing
                Debug.Print countMoved
            Else
                'Not OK
                Debug.Print countMoved
                'From the starting point after "found"
                rngFound.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                rngFound.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
                rngFound.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand much, please add some example by edit your question. Maybe, i met same case in past.
Example: 
Case 1:

```
The dog can go but the bird can fly.
```

Header break this paragraph:

```
The dog can go but
Header begining- header content
the bird can fly.
```

My simple solution is using Find and Replace dialog, click "More >>" button, check the checkbox "Use wildcards"  and type formula in Find what:

```
^13Header begining*^13
```

Let "Replace with" box blank. Then click Replace all. It will delete header line and join the previous paragraph with the next one. (^13 is paragraph mark, * mean 0 or more characters)

Case 2:

```
The dog can go.(without space at the end)
The bird can fly.
```

Header at between 2 paragraphs:

```
The dog can go.
Header begining- header content
The bird can fly.
```

Like case 1 but change formula in Find what:

```
.^13Header begining*^13
```

Type in "Replace with" box:

```
.^p
```

Then click Find next to manual fix if you see each find result is different, or click Replace all if you think all result are the same.
If you want to care period or quotation mark or more, put them all into [ ]
Find what:

```
([."])^13Header begining*^13
```

Replace with:

```
\1^p
```

Maybe your case is not same with 2 above case. If so, we need change formula. 
By the way, you can try convert PDF to Word as below:
Right click on pdf file > Open with > Microsoft Word.

Word will convert your pdf file to Word file. May this way help you have less header issue.